# find with keywords but skip folders

Tags: bash, find, keyword

I'm using the following command to find specific file extensions within folders,sub-sub-sub folders etc. However, it also return results if a folder/directory that has that particular keyword as well. How can I bypass this?

```
find . \( -type d -a ! -name 'downloading' -a ! -name 'vntdone' -a ! -name '.' \) -o -name \*.avi -o -name \*.mkv -o -name \*.mp4 -o -name \*.VOB
```

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure I understand the need for your first parameters, but is this what you're looking for?

```
find . -type f \(  -name \*.avi -o -name \*.mkv -o -name \*.mp4 -o -name \*.VOB \)
```

This will output files names ending with `avi`, `mkv`, `mp4` and `VOB`

Comment: I need it to output the folders that the file is in as well... but don't output results without filenames because a folder may have keyword: MP4 in it...

Comment: what you recommended also very good, but if a folder names has spaces it breaks the result into pieces, can we fix this?

Comment: @thevoipman What do you mean it breaks the result into pieces? it gives one result per line. Do you need to give this output to another command which has problems parsing an output with spaces? if so, please post the command and I'll help you fix it :)

Comment: If a folder has whitespaces/spaces in between each word, it gives each result it's own line. :)

Comment: @thevoipman I tested it with this: `mkdir "A FOLDER"; touch "A FOLDER"/a.avi "A FOLDER"/b.mkv` and I have this result: 1st line with `./A FOLDER/a.avi`, second line with  `./A FOLDER/b.mkv`. Not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: You're right, how do I exclude a certain keyword from the searches?